# How is bias added in a convolutional layer

Tags: cnn

In a typical neural network , bias is usally added like this

```
 v = activation ( w1*x1+ ... + Wb*b)
```

However, I am not really sure how it is done in convolutional layer. My one thought is that it is added with each convoltional operation for a neuron. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways bias is usually added to a convolutional layer:

- **Tied bias**: where you share one bias per kernel
- **Untied bias**: where you use use one bias per kernel and output

Check [this](https://harmdevries89.wordpress.com/2015/03/27/tied-biases-vs-untied-biases/) blog post comparing the two.

Other than that, bias **isn't really necessary** in CNNs. There are many popular implementations which ignore it altogether (e.g. [ResNet-152](https://github.com/adamcasson/resnet152/blob/master/resnet152.py#L132)).